# How to set repeat regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have regular expression `^\d{5}$|^\d{5}-\d{4}*$"` it checked US zip.
But I need check "`zip, zip, zip`" how to do this?

I tried this `^(\d{5}$|^\d{5}-\d{4},)*$` but it not work

Comment: Is it consistently three occurrences, or an undefined number?

Comment: If you have repetitions, do not put `$` inside the repeating block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
((^|, )(\d{5}|\d{5}-\d{4}))*$
```

Tester: http://regexr.com?36297

Each match must be preceded by `(^|, )`, so by the beginning of the string or a `,` (comma space)

Note that you shouldn't use the `\d` in .NET, because `٠١٢٣٤` are `\d`! (in .NET `\d` includes non-ASCII Unicode digits). `[0-9]` is normally better.

Comment: Good, I needed space add `12345, 12345`

Comment: @Mediator Use this: `((^|,\s*)(\d{5}|\d{5}-\d{4}))*$`

Answer (score 0):

The expression you appear to need is:

```
    ^\d{5}(|-\d{4})(,\d{5}(|-\d{4}))*$
```

The one you were attempting to write was:

```
    ^(\d{5}|\d{5}-\d{4},)*$
```

but that would require every ZIP to have a trailing comma, which the very last one would not have had.

Breaking down the answer given,

- `\d{5}(|-\d{4})` is a variant of your original, but simply making the -1234 optional.
- `(,\d{5}(|-\d{4}))*` is the first regular expression preceded by a comma, and allowed zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this for speed:

```
 ^\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?(?:,\s*\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)*$
```

expanded

```
 ^ 
 \d{5} 
 (?: - \d{4} )?
 (?:
      , \s* \d{5} 
      (?: - \d{4} )?
 )*
 $
```

and this for speed/flexibility:

```
 ^\s*\d{5}(?:\s*-\s*\d{4})?(?:\s*,\s*\d{5}(?:\s*-\s*\d{4})?)*\s*$
```

expanded

```
 ^ 
 \s* 
 \d{5} 
 (?: \s* - \s* \d{4} )?
 (?:
      \s* , \s* \d{5} 
      (?: \s* - \s* \d{4} )?
 )*
 \s* 
 $
```